# How to call anaconda environment to run specific package of python(2.7) from other python(3.7) script via os.system()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I have two directories at the same level. For example Folder A and Folder B. Folder A uses python3.7 and Folder B has an Anaconda environment which uses python2.7. I run `os.system("python ../folder b/ex2.py")`.

[image: Drawing of hierarchy explained above.]

In folder B the Anaconda environment is activated.

The problem is when I run the python script from Terminal `python ../folder b/ex2.py` it runs successfully but when I call the script from folder A it doesn't use the Anaconda environment.

Comment: specify the entire path to the python 2.7 executable.

Comment: Please add quick code snippets which show the folder structure and the pseudo-contents of each script. It will be easier to visualize and answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your conda env is name `python2.7`. Change

```py
os.system('python ../folderb/ex2.py')
```

to

```py
os.system('conda activate python2.7 && python ../folderb/ex2.py')
```

This should execute your ex2.py within the conda env.

Comment: This may be correct answer. However, in my environment the conda activte doesn't work properly and the following error occured.
```CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell```
Even I run conda init <SHELL_NAME>, the error doesn't disappear. This may be I can't fully configure the conda and other ubuntu. But I can run the other file via the following command.
```os.system('conda run -n <env_name> python <path_to_other_script>')```

Answer (score 0):

run the other file via the following command.

```
os.system('conda run -n <env_name> python <path_to_other_script>')
```