# Calling another python script in a different conda environment (using subprocess)

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I have two scripts `A.py` and `B.py` which runs in different conda environments on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

I would like to use `A.py` to call `B.py` by opening a bash shell, calling "conda activate envB", followed by "python B.py args". However, neither of the attempts below work:

Attempt 1) :

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['conda', 'activate', 'envB'])

for i in range(10):
    subprocess.call(['python', 'B.py', i])
```

- I'm getting an error message suggesting conda is not properly set up: `CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'. To initialize your shell, run .....`
- I tried adding `subprocess.call(['source', '~/.bashrc'])` to setup the environment paths but the shell seems to be complaining `No such file or directory: 'source': 'source'`

Attempt 2)

```
subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', '-i', '-c', "conda activate myenv"])
subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', '-i', '-c', "echo $(which python) >> test.txt"])
for i in range(10):
    subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', '-i', '-c', "python B.py -{}".format(i)])
```

- This doesn't seem to activate myenv. Is there any way to keep the shell open after the first command?
- This also appears to create a background process that continues to run after I've terminated A.py. B.py appears to run in the background but I can't kill it using bash.

Attempt 3)

I also tried using `os.system(command)` but can't figure out how to load environment variables with os.system.
Hence this doesn't work either: [How to call anaconda environment to run specific package of python(2.7) from other python(3.7) script via os.system()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55643622/how-to-call-anaconda-environment-to-run-specific-package-of-python2-7-from-oth)

Comment: What version of conda are you using and what OS are you running this on?

Comment: conda 4.6.8, Ubuntu 18.04 if that matters.

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47246350/conda-activate-not-working, I'd try executing that minus the `conda` - i.e. `activate envB`.

Comment: conda activate is working. `subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', '-i', '-c', "echo $(which python) >> test.txt"])` is printing the correct python path to test.txt. But somehow it freezes my computer.